# How accurately can an ESC detect the number of RPMs?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am working on a project involving brushless motors, so I got an ESC to power them. The problem, is that I need to accurately control the number of RPM.

Can an ESC, [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DU49XXS), control the number of RPM the motor is doing? Or is it based more on percentage of throttle?

If I wanted to accurately control the number of RPM my motor is doing, would I have to get an optical RPM sensor?

Comment: That's an ESC for *brushed* motors, not brushless. As such, it simply varies the terminal voltage being sent to the motor, probably using PWM. If you're using it with brushless motors, then the motors are doing their commutating internally, and it won't generally be possible to get a speed reading directly from the motor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, an ESC can precisely know the RPM, since it's the ESC that provides the RPM.

The whole way that a brushless DC motor works is about exciting individual coils.  As subsequent coils are turned on / off the magnet is pulled around the circle.  Only when all the coils have been used in turn has one revolution takes place.

Since it's the ESC that is responsible for creating that sequence of coil activations it's the ESC that dictates exactly how fast the motor is turning.

But the real question you should be asking is, can you control the RPM setting of the ESC to any great accuracy?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Can you answer the rephrased question?

Comment: Do you fancy re-phrasing the question so it makes more sense?

Comment: Besides, I think the answer to the question is: "Only the manufacturer of that ESC can know", since there is no documentation - no datasheet, nothing, so we can't know what it does.

Comment: Alright, so probably gonna have to use an optical RPM sensor. Thanks!